# Badge в TextView

Tags: android

Всем привет,

Имеется `RecyclerView`, в нем находятся **n-количество** `cells`. Каждая `cell` имеет `TextView`.
Как можно нарисовать **точку** на этом `TextView`, но что бы она **была поверх** этого `cell` ?

P.S `padding` между `cell` не должен быть, так получилось нарисовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно создать свою разметку для элемента списка с учетом ваших требований. Вот например простые квадраты:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="First is below"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=" Last is on top"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

вот как выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Вот есть вопрос-первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821684/is-it-possible-to-place-one-view-over-another-in-android#:%7E:text=Just%20in%20case%20if%20you,on%20top%20of%20the%20button.&text=You%20can%20also%20do%20it,new%20layout%20introduced%20by%20google.). По сути вам нужно создавать такую штуку самому:

1. Сделать одну вьюху поверх другой.
2. Засетить фон из drawable который
3. Подогнать по расположеню

Вот если сделать все что описано выше получается такая разметка элемента списка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Some text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="20" />

</FrameLayout>
```

вот drawable фон:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#f00" />

    <solid android:color="#f00" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
        android:radius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

вот итог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ну а дальше уже сетите это все в адаптере списка и подгоняете размеры.

Comment: Спасибо ! Но если сделать так,  то этот badge будет внутри cell. И если будет большой размер он не будет выходить через границы cell, а будет обрезанным.

Comment: @kxko, это пример, а не реализация вашей задачи. На основе его можно понять, что все зависит только от того, как вы это реализуете. Направление в данном ответе дано верное. Если вы хотите конкретное решение для своей задачи, то в вопросе нужно приводить конкретную разметку и проблему в отображении.

Comment: @kxko, да этот вариант еще требует доработки, но как сказал предыдущий комментатор это всего лишь пример того что можно положить в основу для решение вашей задачи :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.